# iPhone 7 simulator is not found on Xcode 11 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, ios13, iphone7plus

I have downloaded **Xcode 11 beta** and create a project for **iOS 13.0**.

When I search on target *simulator device*. There is only *iPhone 8 to iPhone XR* only available.

*iPhone 7 and iPhone 7Plus* is missing.

Help me.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the iPhone 7 if the simulator of the iPhone 8 is the same?

Comment: Must agree with Kathiresan on this one, the iPhone 8 simulator is exactly the same as the iPhone 7... no difference at all

Comment: I know that but previous version Apple was mentioned as separately.

Answer (score 14):

You can Add New Simulators..

click on Simulators part -> add Additional Simulators -> select simulators -> click on plus icon -> give simulator name and device type and os version -> create..now you can see your create simulator..

here is images - >[Open Add simulators option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrFd7.png)
[Create New Simulators which You want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkeqh.png)

Comment: Can I have any reference link?

Comment: @KathiresanMurugan please check My Updated Answer..i hope its Help You.